# What is _addDevId in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I was looking at the tracking code [Google Analyticator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analyticator/) generates and I noticed the line

```
_gaq.push(['_addDevId', 'i9k95']); // Google Analyticator App ID with Google
```

However, I can't find any references to `_addDevId` anywhere in Google's official documentation, and googling it returns nothing but random code snippits (most of which with Google Analyticator's ID.)

What is it, and is there an analytics.js equivalent?

Here's the full generated code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_addDevId', 'i9k95']); // Google Analyticator App ID with Google 

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: Where get this code ?

Comment: It's in the header of my wordpress site that runs Google Analyticator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_addDevId` is a Google Analytics parameter, although it is not commonly used.

> **What’s the _addDevId for?**
>
> This is our ID for the Google Analytics Developer Program. It allows Google to know that the API call comes from the Google Analyticator plugin as Google tracks our API calls. This does not give us any access or knowledge about your site, or analytics data. It is strictly for Google Analytics Developer Program statistical purposes only.

http://www.videousermanuals.com/google-analyticator/#adddevid

Answer (score 0):

_addDevId does not belong to Google Analytics code, is part of a custom implementation of wordpress plugin called: Google Analyticator.

You can check the code snippet, it works fine without that line

Comment: Actually, if you ctrl-f [ga.js](http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js), it's in there. Specifically `a("_addDevId", U[x].V);`